# how to access multiple elements from json in php

Tags: php, json

```
$json = '{"info": {
    "id": "546548",
    "type": "TT-01",
    "name": "Ritz",
    "simno": "",
    "imei": "123",
    "Serial": "123456789876543"
  }}'
```

i want individual elements to print

Comment: Please, describe the issue, you're having.

Comment: Why did you replaye your complete question body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['info']['trackerid']; //Echoes 546548
```

Any further questions?
Should run `print_r($json);` after decoding it to see a visually decent representation.

Comment: Thanks Yellow Bird, I keep forgetting about formatting...

Comment: thanku it is running...

Comment: Mark it as the chosen answer then please

Comment: i am getting this data from a particular url...it is stored in json format in php...how can i access its individual elements in another jvascpt file

Comment: Please explain that better, is the json stored in a php variable or a .json file; where do you want to access the individual elements of the said json content?

Comment: json is stored in a php variable...and i want to access it from my javascript file

Comment: JQuery AJAX Calls can be used to fetch JSON and automatically parse it into an accessible object. You may want to ask another question; not referring to PHP in it.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('getfile.php', function(data) {
alert(data);
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>



my php file is
<?php
$json='{"name":"ram","lname":"katara"}';
$json = json_decode($json,true);
 print_r($json);
?>      how can i get this json into my javascript file

Comment: you should just be running echo on $json in the php, since it has to be transmitted as PHP not as a visual representation. The JQuery code looks to be correct on first glance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this string in your PHP Code. Just pass it to the `json_decode()` function. This will return a normal php object.